# How can i pass extra header Info in Angular and socket.io?

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

Based on what i read and tested on basic javascript clients i can pass extra headers in my Angular Client which will then be avail on my NodeJs server in the
**socket.handshake** . But i am not sure what i am missing or what i am doing wrong since below code does not create

```
async socketInit() {
this.client = io(`${environment.socketUrl}`,  {
    transportOptions: {
      polling: {
        extraHeaders: {
          Authorization: "Bearer authorization_token_here"
        }
      }
    }
  });

    await new Promise((res) => {
        this.client.on('connect', () => {
            this.isConnected = true;
            this.socketId = this.client.id;

            this.client.on('disconnect', () => this.isConnected = false);

            res();
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(`Socket.io error: ${e.message}`));
}
```

for some reason this causes the connect to fail as i can see in my debug console of the angular that socket.io has a TransportError

Comment: did you try with the quotes - `"Authorization": "Bearer authorization_token_here"`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference whats strange is that the same syntax works in a javascript client

Comment: Int the docs (https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-extraHeaders), there is "Custom headers will not be appended when using websocket as the transport". Maybe there is the problem. But it's only a guess.

Comment: Yes i read that as well but even if that is the case it should not create a TransportError

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to connect to a web-socket server on port 5001, while my angular app was opened on port 4200. When I added `extraHeaders` to the client options, the browser started to throw the CORS error like this:

> origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The ports are not the same, and that's the cause of the cross-origin problem.

I've fixed it by setting my web-socket server port, the same as the web server, and opening the webpage on that port.

Comment: After this were you able to send headers from browser to server? Websockets doesnt allow that according to its docs